# Integral around the rectangle

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the integral $1/(z-10-12i)$ round the rectangle with vertices, $7+7i, 12+7i, 12+15i$ and $7+ 15i$ in the anti clockwise direction is $\pi  i/2$?

Comment: Bit lost on what you are asking for. Please rephrease.

Comment: I would like to know if the integral in a rectangle with those vertices in anti-clockwise direction is the answer pii i/2?

Comment: Do you mean the ellipses created by the rectangle? What do you mean by " integral in a rectangle with those vertices in anti-clockwise direction"?

Comment: i believe it is

Comment: I found it I need to use Green theorem

Comment: You have to use Cauchy Integral formula.

Comment: And answer will be $2\pi i$.

Answer (score 1):

I think, is just $2\pi i$ because 10+12i is into the rectangle and by Cauchy's integral formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula).

Comment: I agree with you. It's pretty obvious.